# Populate array with values from different <option> drop down

Tags: php, arrays, select, while-loop

I find this concept kinda confusing.

So basically i have a while loop in PHP that is used to retract display a question and its possible answers from a database. I also have populated a drop down list ( using select tag) with those possible answers. What im trying to achieve is, through a form, to send an array with values from all the currently selected options of the  tag. This is the part of the code if that makes it easier to understand.

```
                echo "<select name='quiz_question' id='quiz_question' required>";
                while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $answer = $row['answer'];
                    $answer_id = $row['id'];

                    echo "<option value='$answer_id'>$answer</option>";
                }

                echo "</select>";
```

Any ideas on how i could achieve populating an array with elements that have the same value name since they are in a loop it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer that i was looking for. Posting it here in case someone else stumbles across my question.

Bare in mind that i'm populating my array with "id" which is an integer.

```
     echo "<select name='Quiz_answers[]' id='quiz_question' >";

              while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

                  $answer = $row['answer'];
                  $answer_id = $row['id'];
                  echo "<option value='$answer_id'>$answer</option>";
              }

            echo "</select>";
```